# CentOS can't remove user from group

Tags: users, group

Asked and answered many times, but I can't get it working!!!

(On CentOS) I have the user userA and I want to remove it from group `sftponly`.

```
#groups userA
userA : sftponly
#id -Gn userA
sftponly
#gpasswd -d userA sftponly
Removing user userA from group sftponly
gpasswd: unknown member userA

#tail /etc/group
userA:x:509:
sftponly:x:510:
#tail /etc/passwd
userA:x:509:510::/home/userA:/bin/bash/
```

so gpasswd not working. Also:

```
usermod -G fourpoints fourpoints
```

No result.

I don't know really what to do, I'm not sure about editing /etc/group either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's necessary first to change the main group to the userA:

```
#usermod -g userA userA
```

and then the user can be removed from the group with gpasswd

Comment: This answer, plus @chris-olin allowed me to remove a user from a group that was their current default, without getting errors like: `gpasswd: user 'userA' is not a member of 'sftponly'`. This was on Centos 7.

Answer (score 19):

Ran into the same issue. Was able to do the following to resolve this:

`gpasswd -d user group`

Comment: No idea why this answer has not been upvoted. It's best practice!

Comment: As pointed out by @glasnhost, this does not work if the group you want to remove, is the users main group; on Centos 7 anyways. Switching the main group first, then running `gpasswd` no longer gives me errors like `gpasswd: user 'userA' is not a member of 'sftponly'`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot remove this user from  that group given it's the only group that they're a member of. This is evident in the output being returned to you by the `groups userA` command:

```
$ groups userA
userA : sftponly
```

Also the `id` output:

```
$ id -Gn userA
sftponly
```

Look in the `/etc/passwd` file for this user, this is most probably their primary group. You'll have to either move them to another group (by changing their primary in `/etc/passwd`) or delete their account entirely.